# Error installing 1.9.3 with RVM on Lion

Tags: ruby, installation, osx-lion

I have burned an embarrassing number of hours trying to install ruby and rails on Mac.
I am using Lion 10.7.2, Xcode 4.2.1, rvm 1.10.0, and gcc 4.2.1
Does anyone have a surefire way to install ruby with rvm. Or, is there

```
rvm install 1.9.2 -C --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

Produces the error

```
make[1]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make: *** [mkmain.sh] Error 1
```

Running

```
rvm install 1.9.3-p0  --with-gcc=clang
```

Produces the error

```
make: *** [.rbconfig.time] Abort trap: 6
```

Simply running

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```

Produces the error

```
make[2]: *** [../../.ext/x86_64-darwin11.2.0/tcltklib.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/tk/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

From reading [this](http://hello.keewooi.com/ruby-1-9-3-preview-1-available-now/), I ran the below in the Terminal and my Mac would not restart until I put the libiconv.2.dylib back in place using Target Disk Mode.

```
rm /usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
ln -s /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib /usr/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143568/cant-install-ruby-1-9-1-on-macosx-10-6) link, I also removed a previous install of Macfuse which is known to cause problems

I have reinstalled Xcode twice [Install Xcode from the Application Folder].

Is there another way to get Ruby Installed on Lion?
Many thanks as I'm fast running out of ideas
Graham

Comment: Note that lines `make: *** ...` aren't as useful as you might think. That's just `make(1)` reporting that one of the commands it tried to execute reported an error. Including that command and any output it might have generated would be much more useful.

Answer (score 9):

The following worked for me:

```
$ rvm install 1.9.3 --with-gcc=clang
```

I got that from [this page](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/534).

Comment: Right. The key part is '--with-gcc=clang'

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too and tried several of the listed solutions unsuccessfully. Then I downloaded **XCode 4.3.1 for Lion** and the **Xcode command line tools update** (dated March 7, 2012) from Apple's developer site and just re-ran 'rvm install 1.9.3'. Worked perfectly and installed 1.9.3p125.

Hope this helps

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. I did what Bill here says, 4.3.3 XCode, go to preferences and install 'command line tools update' and bam. Worked.

Answer (score 2):

Note that RVM itself tells you that it won't work with XCode 4.2:

> ** Lion Users: DO NOT use Xcode Version 4.2.x for OS X Lion. It currently fails to build several rubies and gems,
>   as well as several Homebrew and Macports packages as well. Xcode Version 4.1 (4B110) works.

You can see this warning again by calling `rvm requirements`.

The simplest (albeit slow) way to fix the problem is to remove XCode 4.2 and download and install XCode 4.1. You can also apparently fix it with a separate gcc-4.2 installation, but I don't know the details of how you'd do that.

For more detail, see the [full discussion on the rvm github tracker](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/534)

Comment: Not sure if this still applies; my requirements tell me this: `** Lion Users: Xcode Version 4.2.x for OS X Lion works only for ruby 1.9.3-p0 (or higher). It currently fails to build several other rubies and gems, ...`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem on my 10.7.2 server with Xcode 4.2.1. Installing [this](https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer) stand-alone gcc compiler (sourced from apple), did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to force autoconf.

> rvm install 1.9.3 --force-autoconf

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to install ruby by using macports and Xcode 4.2.1. Had to abandon rvm.

```
port install ruby19 +nosuffix
```

Thanks for all of the answers and help :)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
rvm pkg install iconv
rvm pkg install readline  
rvm remove 1.9.3
rvm install 1.9.3 --with-iconv-dir=$rvm_path/usr --with-readline-dir=$rvm_path/usr
```

source: http://blog.merjis.com/2011/12/18/rails-3-1-ruby-1-9-3-lion-xcode-4-1/